# Firebug is skipping lines after $(document).ready(function() while debugging

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug, lines

I just want to create a dynamic URL. I am calling the listServices method and it is working as expected where as the getPortNumber which i am calling from listService is not working. I added dubug point in getPortNumber method. I am getting value for domainValue but I am not able to debug after $(document).ready(function(). The control directly goes to return portNumber and in the final URL i am getting the port number value as undefined. I checked and validated the port_url (json file). my json file looks like this

```
{
"servers": [
    {
        "listeningPort": "6080",
        "shutdownPort": "8180",
        "redirectPort": "8443",
        "sslPort": "8443",
        "openWirePort": "61610",
        "jmxPort": "9332",
        "category": "Test A"
    }
}
```

I got struck. I hope this issue is not becoz of calling javascript method from another method.

```
function getPortNumber()
{
  var portNumber;
       var domainValue = $("#domain").val();

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON(port_url, function(result) {
            $.each(result, function() {
                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                    if (v.category == domainValue) {
                        portNumber = v.listeningPort;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return portNumber;
}


function listServices()
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#list").text("");
            var jList = $("#list");
            var listOfServers = $("#servers").text();
            var serverArray = listOfServers.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < serverArray.length; i++)
            {
                var port = getPortNumber();
                var tempURL = "http://"+serverArray[i].trim().toLowerCase()+".javaworkspace.com:"+port+"/services/listServices";
                jList.append("<li><a href="+tempURL+" target='_blank'>"+tempURL+"</a></li>");
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: document.ready will never be executed if inside a function. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uxyKS/

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to call `document.ready` inside a function.....since (i bet) that function is called after document is ready...

remove that

```
function getPortNumber()
{
   var portNumber;
   var domainValue = $("#domain").val();



    $.getJSON(port_url, function(result) {
        $.each(result, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                if (v.category == domainValue) {
                    portNumber = v.listeningPort;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });

 return portNumber;
}
```

and do the same for the other one..

Comment: After removing $(document).ready(function() from getPortNumber the debug skip code after 
$.getJSON(port_url, function(result) {. Firebug is not reporting any errors.

Comment: You need to place a breakpoint inside the callback (where the `if` statement is), not on the `.$getJSON()`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to learn the art of stepping into callback functions in the javascript debugger.  It doesn't quite work the simple way you'd like.  It won't step into a callback function even thought the callback function looks like the logical next line of execution.  Technically it isn't.  When you say to step over a line of code, it steps over everything that line of code does including any callback functions that it calls.

When you step over `$(document).ready(function()` and the document is not yet ready, it does NOT execute the callback function and the debugger does not go into that function.  So, if you want to see what happens when that callback function is actually executed, you have to manually put a breakpoint in that callback function.  You can't just step into it line by line.

The same is true of your `$.getJSON(port_url, function(result) {` call and your `$.each()` call.  When you say to step over the `$.each()` function, it literally steps over that function and onto the next line after that function.  That skips the entire callback.  If you want to step into the `$.each()`, you have to either manually set a breakpoint in the callback or you have to single step into the `$.each()` implementation in jQuery and watch it eventually call your callback.

So in this code:

```
function getPortNumber()
{
  var portNumber;
       var domainValue = $("#domain").val();

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON(port_url, function(result) {
            $.each(result, function() {
                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                    if (v.category == domainValue) {
                        portNumber = v.listeningPort;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return portNumber;
}
```

If you want to see what happens in the inner `$.each()` loop, you will have to set a breakpoint on this line `if (v.category == domainValue) {` and let the code run until it hits that breakpoint.  Single stepping through getPortNumber() in the debugger will encounter problems at each of the four places that you use callback functions: `$(document).ready()`, `$.getJSON()`, `$.each()` and `$.each()`.  So, to get inside of those, you will want to set a breakpoint inside them and let the code run until it hits that breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If some error exist there then it will skip.

Why you used `$(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score 0):

After removing $(document).ready(function() from getPortNumber the debug skip code after 
$.getJSON(port_url, function(result) {. Firebug is not reporting any errors.